# Is there any way to change the location of a custom folder in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10

As you can see below, Windows User folders have **Location** option when you check their properties.

[image]

Now, the **Downloads** folder is actually located in C drive. But I changed its location to my E drive.

For normal folders (that we create manually), this feature doesn't exist.

**Why I need this:**

Microsoft **OneDrive** only syncs selected folders like Desktop, Documents, Pictures etc.

I need to sync 1-2 other folders that are in other partitions of the disk. For some reasons, I *can't* (I don't want actually) move them to any of the above mentioned User folders.

So what I'm thinking is to create a new folder inside Documents and change its location to whatever I need to sync.

Is it possible?

Comment: In order to move user-created folders, you would move the folder like any other folder or file to the desired location.

Comment: You said you can't move a normal folder to a different place. What error do you get when you try?

Comment: Kindly check edit @Ronaldo @ Ramhound

Answer (score -1):

Custom folders must be cut and paste to the new place.

About your situation with OneDrive, when you add an account to OneDrive on your desktop you're asked to choose the location of OneDrive folder, like this:

[image: OneDrive folder location]

As you can see, it has a default folder that you can change (to drive E as you wish). After that, OneDrive will sync any folder you place inside the folder you have chosen.
You're asked to choose a location every time you unlink and add an account to your OneDrive.